# ¿Cómo enviar mas de 1 parámetro en Javascript y PHP por GET?

Tags: php, javascript, web

Tengo este código ya funcionando que me ordena, pero requiero enviar 2 parámetros para poder tabular. Vi otras soluciones pero debo reestructurar más de lo que pensaba, quiero saber si ¿Puedo seguir usando este código con unos cambios menores?

```
$.get('ordenaAlgo.php?rango='+ordenarTabla, function(data, status, request){
  data.datos.forEach(function(reg) {
    nom=reg.nombre;
    dir=reg.direccion;
    ema=reg.email;
    eli=reg.idpersonal;
    mostrarDatos(nom, dir, ema, eli);

  });
});
```

Comment: Esta es la forma más común para mandar más parámetros por get `'ordenaAlgo.php?rango='+ordernarTabla+'id='+idOrdenarTabla+'...` ahora desconozco los cambios que mencionas y de que forma te afecta hasta que no los apliques.

Answer (score 6):

La forma de enviar varios parámetros por `GET` sería concatenar los parámetros mediante `&`

```
$.get('ordenaAlgo.php?rango='+ordenarTabla+'&rango2='+ordenarTabla2, function(data){...}
```

O la forma más legible sería, enviarlo como segundo parámetro de `$.get`

```
$.get('ordenaAlgo.php', {'rango': ordenarTabla, 'rango2': ordenarTabla2} , function(data) {
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, la forma mas legible me ayudo muchísimo