# Como envio una variable por GET AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$("div#enviarpost").click(function(){
    ididea =$("#ididea").val();
    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("ididea",ididea );                                       
        $.ajax({

            url:"views/ajax/ideas.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(respuesta){
                console.log(respuesta);         
            }
         });
  });
```

`HTML` donde envió

```
<form>
      <input id="ididea" type="number" value="'.$item["id_idea"].'"  hidden>
      <a href="ideas" id="enviarpost" class="btn waves-effect white grey-text darken-text-2" >Mostrar Idea</a>
            </form>
```

y donde recibo no llega coloco

```
echo $_GET["ididea"];
```

Comment: Cambie el `type` del `ajax` por `GET` , lo demás es igual a un petición `POST`, también puede pasar por [esta pregunta relacionada.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66046/c%C3%B3mo-enviar-mas-de-1-par%C3%A1metro-en-javascript-y-php-por-get/66050#66050)

Comment: como hago para resivrila en otro lado ?

Comment: corrijo yo capturo con el id ya que estoy usando jquery, mi probelma es que cuando envio el get solo me agarra un id

Comment: amigo la variable se envia el problema que tengo es que cuando llega a la otra pagina la variable no la coje ya que se pierde cuando la pagina se recarga